# Facing issue to connect MongoDBCompass to backend

Tags: mongodb, backend, mongodb-compass

I am facing problem while connecting mongodbCompass to Backend
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kanwW.png)

i trying it to connect backend, but i am facing difficulty to initilize db in mongodb compass, in backend i have connected it, its my first db in mogodbcompass

Comment: Did you click `Connect`?

Comment: Please ensure that you have started the MongoDB. Please run `mongod --version` command in your terminal. if it returns version details then you can check if you have set the password or user for your mongo.

Answer (score 0):

when facing issue on mongodb compass make sure that the connection string is correct with that of nodejs backend,

Comment: this answer could be a comment in the question. Also, your answer looks like a suggestion than an answer